# According to the Qur'an or Hadith, is it permissible for a Muslim to lie in some circumstances?

Tags: quran, hadith, lying

According to the Qur'an or Hadith, is it permissible for a Muslim to lie in some circumstances?

If so, under what circumstance may a Muslim lie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lying is forbidden except in [three instances](http://sunnah.com/urn/672410), and they are:

1. To please ones wife
2. lying during/in war
3. and to try to bring people together

Lying outside of these three (exceptions) is haram/forbidden.  Furthermore I would like to point out that even if a lie is told in these three situations, it shouldn't be a lie that brings trouble and problems, in other words be harmful.

And concerning the second exception "lying in/during war" an example for it would be if a leader would be taking his army to war, he would conceal information of the place of battle from the enemy by outright saying that we are going to go to "such a place" but go to another but concealing that information.  And I would like to point out that the one who tells a lie for instance to bring people together and fix problems between them, he/she isn't considered a liar:

> ‏ليس الكذاب الذي يصلح بين الناس فينمي خيرًا، أو يقول خيرًا
>
> 'The person who (lies) in order to conciliate between people is not a
>   liar, when he conveys good or says (something) good

May Allah forgive my mistakes.

Comment: Understood. شكراً. Should I presume that the Qurʾān itself makes no explicit reference to this matter, then?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 The exceptions are from the Sunnah of Allah's Messenger.

Comment: I understand. That is part of the ʾaḥādīṯ, though, correct? Otherwise you would have cited an āyah from the Qurʾān, correct? So that is why I asked if I should presume that the Qurʾān itself makes no explicit reference to this matter.

Comment: still, must be some circumstances in each of these 3 cases, can`t be all sorts of lies

Comment: too quickly accepted-- a lot more details to this. there's a *huge* difference between lying and deception.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 yes, it is in the Hadith where it mentions this, I do not know a place in the Quran where it mentions or where it explicitly mentions this, either way the exceptions for lying has been authentically reported from the Prophet himself, and that is what is accepted.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 thanks for response, saw it just now. my comment above explains my concern. not directly about your fine answer.

Comment: @ashley: If you can provide a better answer, I'll change my selected best answer. In fact, that's my policy. Stack Exchange sites should always ultimately reward what is the best answer, whether it comes now or later. So, don't let that stop you or others from submitting an answer. :)

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 <H3br3wHamm3r81>, no, I don't have a better answer myself. this ans.doesn't seem wrong to me but incomplete still. didn't want to skip and not point out on such a delicate matter. just my personal thoughts BTW-- i'm not a scholar on the topic.